# Why does IE 10 use two different cookies for two requests to the same site?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am maintaining a java web system based on springboot. Recently, a 401 error was found in some IE 10 requests. Then I checked my system and this is the result I got:

1. There is no problem with Chrome;
2. On IE10, these two requests use different cookies to visit the same website, as shown in the following two pictures:
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Is there a subdomain or preceding www.?

www.example.com and example.com are considered to be different domains, so they will sometimes use different cookies (depending on how cookies are assigned)

Comment: What is the user agent? IE often does an IE7 call to see if there is a sharepoint server

Comment: @ihatzi I have updated these images to show the URL, and as you can see, there is no problem with the domain.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, I don't know what it is, could you please tell me how to check it?